# Static Variables in Python

Tags: python-3.x, static

I was trying to understand how to declare static variables in python and came across this question: [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/class-static-variables-and-methods)

I did understand it and was initially trying to use it for solving DP questions on Leetcode, trying to use a static variable instead of sending the variables as argument in every function call.
Then I wrote a sample code to try to understand how it actually works and its throwing me off because the output is not at all like what I expected it to be. Here is the code:

```
class xyz:
    a = 10
    def func():
        xyz.a = 20
    print(a)
    def func2():
        print(xyz.a)
print(1)
ob1 = xyz()
print(2)
xyz.func2()
print(3)
xyz.func()
print(4)
xyz.func2()
print(5)
ob2 = xyz()
```

And here is the output I got:

```
10
1 
2 
10
3 
4 
20
5
```

From what I had understood till now the code is supposed to be executed line by line right? Then why is the output starting with 10 and not 1?

Another question: I read that passing variables in each function call adds to the stack memory which is the main reason why I'm trying to figure out how to do it with static variables. Is that approach good or am I just wasting time on nothing?

I tried executing the above mentioned piece of code and the output was not what I expected it to be. I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: When the class xyz is defined, the print statement inside the class will be executed. Since you have `print(a)` inside the xyz class, that's why you can see that result 10 is printed first.

Comment: Think about it: static variables might save on stack memory, but they take up global space. What if we have lots of them? And in multi-threaded scenarios, they can cause issues since they're shared. We need to weigh these pros and cons. If the concern is stack memory, maybe we should consider other solutions like iterative methods or even just increasing the stack size.

Comment: If you want `print(a)` to be executed when you create an object by writing `xyz()`, then `print(a)` should ***not*** be directly under `class xyz:`, but instead it should be inside a `def __init__():` member function inside class `xyz`.

Comment: As your question is about the first print, then the rest of the main code should not be in your question -- it is irrelevant. It should only have `print(1)` noting more. Also, there is no recursion in this code, nor dynamic programming -- removing those tags.

Comment: Thank you for the answers y'all. That question does clear my doubt about why 10 was printed before 1. And @trincot I added DP and recursion tags because I got this doubt when I was trying to do those problems. But I'll remove them

Edit: Oh you already removed them nvm.